# I want to display footer Template Page Number to Right of Page

Tags: css

I am adding some styling to what ultimately ends up being printed as a footer section of a PDF. All I'm trying to do is align the page number display to the right of the page - currently it's displaying on the left:

```
     <table style="margin: 0 30px; position: absolute; float: right">
      <tr style="font-size: 10px; color: #333; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica'; line-height: normal; width: 500px">
      <td style="width: 2px">Page</td>
      <td style="width: 2px" class='pageNumber'></td>
      <td style="width: 2px">of</td>
      <td style="width: 2px" class='totalPages'><td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

I also tried this (with 100% not in quotes):

```
   <table style="margin: 0 30px; position: absolute; float: right; width: 100%;">
```

And this with it in quotes:

```
   <table style="margin: 0 30px; position: absolute; float: right; width: '100%';">
```

But none of the above work. The page number display is still on the far left.

What do I need to adjust to get this to float to the far right of the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this solution. I have removed the `position`, `flex` and the `margin` attribute.

```html
<table style="width: 100%;">
  <tr
    style="font-size: 10px; color: #333; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica'; line-height: normal; width: 500px">
    <td></td>
    <td style="width: 2px">Page</td>
    <td style="width: 2px" class='pageNumber'>5</td>
    <td style="width: 2px">of</td>
    <td style="width: 2px" class='totalPages'>10
    </tr>
  </tr>
</table>
```

There is no need to add the width aswell if you wish. Just add `margin-left: auto` to the table.

```html
<table style="margin-left: auto;">
  <tr
    style="font-size: 10px; color: #333; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica'; line-height: normal; width: 500px">
    <td style="width: 2px">Page</td>
    <td style="width: 2px" class='pageNumber'>5</td>
    <td style="width: 2px">of</td>
    <td style="width: 2px" class='totalPages'>10
    </tr>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try below updated code.

```html
<table style="margin: 0 30px; float: right">
      <tr style="font-size: 10px; color: #333; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica'; line-height: normal; width: 500px">
      <td style="width: 2px">Page</td>
      <td style="width: 2px" class='pageNumber'></td>
      <td style="width: 2px">of</td>
      <td style="width: 2px" class='totalPages'><td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: Can you please share screen shot?

Comment: I have updated my answer in runnable mode please check